# How can I send confirmation emails from MediaWiki to users?

Tags: php, email, smtp, mediawiki, pear

**I want my wiki to be able to send confirmation e-mails (i.e: *Confirm e-mail address*) to registered users.** - that simple

In my **Windows XP SP3** box I have installed:

MediaWiki version: 1.23.3
PHP version: 5.4.25(apache2handler)
MySql version: 5.6.17-log

In the same machine I get the following output from command-prompt (CMD) :

`D:\www\php\pear> pear list`

Output:

`INSTALLED PACKAGES, CHANNEL PEAR.PHP.NET:`
`========================================`
`PACKAGE           VERSION      STATE`
`Archive_Tar       1.3.12       stable`
`Auth_SASL         1.0.6        stable`
`Consoloe_Getopt   1.3.1        stable`
`Mail              1.2.0        stable`
`Net_SMTP          1.6.2        stable`
`Net_Socket        1.0.14       stable`
`PEAR              1.9.5        stable`
`Structures_Graph  1.0.4        stable`
`XML_Util          1.2.3        stable`

In my LocalSettings.php I have:

`#SMTP setup`
`$wgSMTP = array(`
 
`'host' => "mydomain.com",`
 
`'port' => 25,`
 
`'auth' => true,`
 
`'username' => "user@mydomain.com",`
 
`'password' => "myPassword",`
 
`);`

In my DefaultSettings.php I have

`$wgSMTP = false;`

In my php.ini I have : (note that is comented with ';' at the beginning (this by default))
`;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"`

## My Error Log

(stacktrace when attempting to send user e-mail confirmation):

`[e41daf7d] /wiki/index.php?title=Special:ConfirmEmail Exception from line 304 of`
 `D:\www\Html\wiki\includes\UserMailer.php: PEAR mail package is not installedBacktrace:`
`#0 D:\www\Html\wiki\includes\User.php(3885): UserMailer::send(MailAddress, MailAddress, string, string, NULL)`
`#1 D:\www\Html\wiki\includes\User.php(3862): User->sendMail(string, string)`
`#2 D:\www\Html\wiki\includes\specials\SpecialConfirmemail.php(77): User->sendConfirmationMail()`
`#3 D:\www\Html\wiki\includes\specials\SpecialConfirmemail.php(58): EmailConfirmation->showRequestForm()`
`#4 D:\www\Html\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPage.php(379): EmailConfirmation->execute(NULL)`
`#5 D:\www\Html\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPageFactory.php(503): SpecialPage->run(NULL)`
`#6 D:\www\Html\wiki\includes\Wiki.php(285): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)`
`#7 D:\www\Html\wiki\includes\Wiki.php(588): MediaWiki->performRequest()`
`#8 D:\www\Html\wiki\includes\Wiki.php(447): MediaWiki->main()`
`#9 D:\www\Html\wiki\index.php(46): MediaWiki->run()`
`#10 {main}`

The stacktrace suggests that the PEAR Mail package is not installed, when clearly I receive a status of **stable** for this package as I mentioned above too ...

What am I doing wrong? ...

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it !!!

In my **php.ini** 
I edited the line 
`;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"`
 to be 
 `include_path = ".;c:\php\includes; c:\php\pear; d:\www\php\pear; d:\www\php\pear\pear"`

That fixed it and now I am receiving notification e-mails ...  :)

Thank you ...

Comment: i am having same issue on linux. how can i solve this. i have tried what you mentioned. does not work

Comment: can you share your log @bonez?